# Control an objects velocity with control surfaces (of sorts)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

It's a bit tricky to explain what exactly I'm trying to do, so let me just give you a scenario:

Imagine you had a missile, trying to hit an aircraft. The missile starts and steers towards a collision course. However, after a while it runs out of fuel. Now it only has its inertia to hit the target, but since it's slowing down, it needs to correct the course. For this it uses its control surfaces.

I want to achieve something like that. Currently I'm just applying a constant force to my missile and simply rotate it towards the direction it needs to go. It has a rigidbody attached and I'm using its drag to slow it down while rotating, so that the constant force I'm applying makes it change direction. Obviously this doesn't work once it runs out of fuel.

So I'm trying to simulate a somewhat realistic 'wing behaviour' to enable it to still turn, without the constant acceleration. Unfortunately I have no idea how to accomplish that and I'm not even sure what I'd have to search for to figure it out.

I tried to reflect the velocity vector, using the line of sight to the target as the normal. Which, I think, should at least give me the correct rotation. But I have no idea how to 'rotate' the velocity towards it in a remotely realistic way. I imagine I'd have to completely ignore Unitys drag and run my own version because in order for a wing to work your drag would have to change depending on the surface area you are exposing, no? And I'm pretty sure that Unity doesn't consider that.

Well, that's about it. If you haven't understood something please ask, it's not all that easy to explain, especially not in a second language.

Any ideas? Any suggested terms I could search for? I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the missile to accelerate, the force must be perpendicular to the velocity vector. This vector could be calculated as a vector rejection:

```
force = c * (direction_to_target - dot(direction_to_target, velocity) / dot(velocity, velocity) * velocity)
```

Where `c` is a factor that transforms the direction vector to a force vector. `direction_to_target` should be a unit vector.

Add the gravity force to accomplish a slow down of the missile.

Comment: Hm. I played with that for a while and it certainly is the right direction. It really looks like it was using wings. It seems to create energy out of nothing, though. It's hard to say what's actually happening from visuals alone and my vector math is not nearly good enough to grasp the equation immediately. However, what I can say is that once the missile loses all its speed, it starts to swing like a leaf in the wind. Only that it's not really falling anymore, it just swings back and forth at a constant height. Also, I had to set c to >20 in order for it to turn fast enough. Might that be it?

Comment: If `velocity` is 0 (or very close to 0), the division will crash. Hence, you should include a check and set `force` to 0 if that' s the case.

Comment: Yea, that helped a bit. However only at somewhat higher values. At velocity > 10 it at least loses altitude again. However it doesn't really fix the problem. I still think it has something to do with that c. Because of that suspicion I just increased c to see if something breaks. And indeed it did. It does infact "generate energy", as in the missile can actually gain altitude at higher values of c. I think the solution might be to seperate the "energy retention" from the "wing span" if you will. In other words, seperate the rotation rate from the energy retained.

Comment: You can also try to do nothing if the missile is moving away from the target (if `dot(direction_to_target, velocity) < 0)`.

Comment: Yes. Or I could just destroy the missile once its velocity tells me that it can't reach the target any longer. I could do all sorts of things to avoid the problem. However that doesn't really fix the problem. I need some control over the turn rate and currently the only way to do that is by increasing c. Which unfortunately also has very bad side effects. Namely the whole creating energy out of nothing thing. I'm starting to think that the whole equation might not be what I need. But even after trying to understand it for a while, I still only have a faint idea about what its even doing :/.